# Return / Get x Number of Items From an Array in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array with over 200 items from a .json file.

I want to know how I can return lets say the first 10 items or 20 items starting from the 7th index/item.

Example

```
OriginalArray = [{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}, {g}, {h}, {i}, {j}, {k}, {l}]
```

How do I get `newArray = [{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}]` or `newArray = [{e}, {f}, {g}, {h}]`

from the `originalArray` in typeScript or Javascript.

Thank you

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: @mplungjan and you think I didn't do that? I don't have a problem if you think this is repeated question.

Comment: I have no way of knowing since you did not post any efforts at all

Comment: @mplungjan I couldn't post a soluton because I dont even know it is done. It is not that I'm getting an error but just that I didn't know there was a simple way to do that.

Comment: for information purpose how did you google it? what was the search term? thank you

Comment: Click the link!!! It’s your title without numbers - I did not have to google when I wrote my answer, I just made the google link for you now to show the first link coming up googling your title was the relevant one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
newArrayA = OriginalArray.slice(0, Math.round(OriginalArray.length/2)) // first half
newArrayB = OriginalArray.slice(Math.round(OriginalArray.length/2)) // second half
```

Comment: Thank you. would `newArrayB` return the value as `newArrayA`?

Comment: `newArrayB` would be the second half of the array. `newArrayA` would be the first half. Notice the arguments are different in the `slice` calls

Comment: got it. When the argument is 1 it uses it as the starting index. When the argument are two it uses the first as the starting index and the second as the ending index, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const offset = 7;
console.log(
  ["{a}", "{b}", "{c}", "{d}", "{e}", "{f}", "{g}", "{h}", "{i}", "{j}", "{k}", "{l}"]
  .slice(offset,offset+4)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```js
var newArray = OriginalArray.slice(7, 7+20);
```